# HTML email Android Outlook app text having weird justification issues

Tags: android, html, email, outlook, text-align

I have one set of text in my html email that Outlook on Android does not like and sets the justification to justify even with text-align:left !important;. Every other client I've tested seems to work just fine.

[sorry for the censorship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpp56.png)

```html
                  <tr bgcolor="#f1f1f1">
                    <td>
                      <table class="session-info" width="90%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="margin: 20px auto 0px auto;">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="150px" height="0px" valign="top" style="margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                            <p style="font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial !important; font-size:1em; color: #666666; font-weight:600; line-height:1.5em; text-align:right;">
                              Session #:
                            </p>
                          </td>
                          <td style="text-align:left;" align="left">
                            <p style="margin:0px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial !important; font-size:1em; color: #666666; font-weight:300; line-height:1.5em; text-align:left;">
                              1234
                            </p>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="150px" height="0px" valign="top">
                            <p style="font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial !important; font-size:1em; color: #666666; font-weight:600; line-height:1.5em; text-align:right;">
                              Session Title:
                            </p>
                          </td>
                          <td style="text-align:left;" align="left">
                            <p style="margin:0px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial !important; font-size:1em; color: #666666; font-weight:300; line-height:1.5em; text-align:left;">
                              Session title is long and is weirdly justified.
                            </p>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="150px" height="0px" valign="top">
                            <p style="font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial !important; font-size:1em; color: #666666; font-weight:600; line-height:1.5em; text-align:right;">
                              Room:
                            </p>
                          </td>
                          <td style="text-align:left;" align="left">
                            <p style="margin:0px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial !important; font-size:1em; color: #666666; font-weight:300; line-height:1.5em; text-align:left;">
                              123
                            </p>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td width="150px" height="0px" valign="top">
                            <p style="font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial !important; font-size:1em; color: #666666; font-weight:600; line-height:1.5em; text-align:right;">
                              Date and Time:
                            </p>
                          </td>
                          <td style="text-align:left;" align="left">
                            <p style="margin:0px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif, Helvetica, Arial !important; font-size:1em; color: #666666 !important; font-weight:300; line-height:1.5em; text-align:left;">
                              <span style="color:#666666;">
                                        <font color="#666666">
                                            Tue, Feb 00, 2017 at 11:15 AM – 12:15 PM
                                        </font>
                                    </span>
                            </p>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The justification can be part of the CSS in the header for the mobile version.

I can think of two things that could be affecting this:

- CSS in the header targeting specific paragraphs or defined as global.
- word spacing can also affect the spacing.

Since i cant see the full code its hard to tell where is happening.

Cheers